# Is the spring "constant" still constant if the spring is circular?

Tags: spring

Imagine a spring with a spring "constant" $k$ which is put on a part of a circular form, say a disc (a slice of a cylinder) with a groove around it to put the spring on. If we stretch the spring it doesn't slip off the disc and friction can be ignored.

What happens to the string constant? Will it get bigger (which is what I think), smaller, stay the same, or isn't it constant anymore?

Comment: Why do you think it would be different than a spring of same length as the circumference?

Comment: I don't say it will be different, but I'm asking **if** it will be different. When you stretch a spring on a circular form it's not stretched in the same way as a linear string is stretched.

Comment: What do you mean by circular form?

Comment: That the spring is wrapped, in part (in its "ground" state), around a circular disk, in a way that the spring doesn't slip off the disk when it's stretched.

Comment: I can't think of a way to set this up where ignoring friction is a reasonable assumption, but I did want to point out that the spring constant has always been an idealization.  Real springs have a spring constant that varies  (oof... okay, I need new wording for that)

Comment: But just for the sake of the argument, let's assume the spring "constant" is really constant when it's linearly stretched and we can let the friction in this setup disappear by some magical lubricant.

Comment: @AdityaGarg-Why the downvote? Isn't this a question which can be answered? Or don't you understand it?

Comment: @descheleschilder didn't downvote

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry! My fault...